# Mesh Collider in unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to programming, 
and am following directions of a book to put together a simple code in javascript.

var Nnet : GameObject;
var theNet= Nnet.AddComponent(MeshCollider);

I tried here to add mesh collider to a gameobject.

it shows error.

How can i add a Mesh Collider to this gameobject.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Comment: i had doubt in unity3d. so what should i tag. please inform that also

Comment: My suggestion is that you click the tag and carefully learn whether it is the thing you are asking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add a BoxCollider Component to the GameObject Nnet. If you want to add a Mesh Collider, try:

```
var theNet= Nnet.AddComponent(MeshCollider);
```

You also have to set the mesh collider(here is theNet)'s sharedMesh if you want to use the collider to collide with other colliders. I suggest you add a mesh collider to a GameObject in the edit mode first. Select a gameobject with a mesh and then try Menu->Component->Physics->Mesh Collider. Once you get familiar with it, you can play with code easily.